# IOS Action Extension Sample Code

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension

i am new to IOS development ,IOS 8 have app extension feature, i have gone through [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2) ,i got some idea what is app extension but i want do sample non UI action extension app example. i tried ui based extension app ,it's working fine.and also i tried  non ui base app but it not working. please can any one explain non ui extension with sample code.

just take simple case Host app will send x and y values to extension , extension need to receive that two values and do some manipulation in extension app and send result to host app and host need to display on ui.

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? That's not enough for anyone to help.